# Enter dynamic database name while executing procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to execute a procedure from another procedure for that I want to enter database name dynamically.

```
            SELECT @dname=dbname FROM @db WHERE id=@intFlag
            PRINT @dname
            EXEC [@dname].[dbo].[IPC_GetCount] @UserLogin,@Role,@Email,@Days,@Code,@Status
```

But it is not accepting the variable even though I am getting db name inside the variable.

Please help

Comment: for that you would need [dynamic SQL](https://www.google.com/search?q=t+sql+dynamic+sql&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=T_SQL+dyn&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3558j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: can you please help with the code

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 - you just build a string containing your SQL and pass it to that procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this query

```
SELECT @dname=dbname FROM   @db WHERE  id=@intFlag

PRINT @dname

DECLARE @query varchar(100) = 'EXEC ['+ @dname +'].[dbo].[IPC_GetCount] '+ @UserLogin +',' + @Role+',' + @Email +',' + @Days+',' +@Code +',' +@Status

EXECUTE (@query)
```

Comment: giving error invalid column name "Invalid column name '@dname'."

Comment: can you try now by  changing [@dbname]  to @dbname

Comment: can you print @query variable and include in comment?   Try with query  execute in your database see  results

Comment: Then some of your variables are NULL please verify your variables are not NULL